# In 2D ragged tensor, how to remove rows have more than 50 element

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use that code from ChatGPT but it have error:

> ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Create a 2D ragged tensor
rt = tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13]*100])

# Find the row lengths
row_lengths = rt.row_lengths()

# Create a boolean mask for rows with length <= 50
mask = row_lengths <= 50

# Index the ragged tensor with the mask to get the rows with length <= 50
rt_new = tf.boolean_mask(rt, mask, axis=0)
```

I have larger 2D ragged tensor and I need to remove all list have move than 50 element. I think it 's simple but I don't see any similar in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `tf.ragged.boolean_mask` instead of `tf.boolean_mask`

```py
tf.ragged.boolean_mask(rt, mask)
# <tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]>
```

Python and TensorFlow are not designed for polymorphism.